# Evaluate Numeric list in pandas column as string list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe from pd.read_csv:

```
| Name     | DOB                     | Country      | Assigned_ID |
| John Doe | [1929/01/17,1910/03/25] | [ML,IND,BY]  | [597212972,12345] |
```

I am trying to evaluate the columns DOB, Country, Assigned_ID as list in the columns so that I can `explode` them later like this:

```
df_data = df_data.explode(["DOB"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So, I tried to convert using `literal_eval`:

```
df_data['DOB'] = df_data['DOB'].apply(literal_eval)
```

which gave me below error.

```
[1929/01/17,1910/03/25]
      ^
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

then I tried to convert the values to str like this:

```
df_data['DOB'] = df_data['DOB'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
```

which failed again with the same error. What am I missing ? Can someone guide me in this?

Expected Output:

```
| Name     | DOB                         | Country            | Assigned_ID |
| John Doe | ['1929/01/17','1910/03/25'] | ['ML','IND','BY']  | ['597212972','12345'] |
```

Comment: Please also post your expected output. Also share a reproducible dataframe so that we can also create the same on our ends.

Comment: I updated the expected output and It is the exact dataframe I have posted.

Comment: So the lists in the input df are not actually lists, but strings?

Comment: df_data.dtypes gives me 'object' for all columns

Comment: Yes it will give `object` only. Can you please share a command to create a sample of your input `df`. I will reproduce it on my end.

Comment: I only have that one row in my df with four columns: Name, DOB, Country, Assigned_ID

Comment: For that one row only, can you please give a df constructor command. I just want to be clear that the columns are actual `lists`, not a string representation of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think the problem is that your arrays contain strings, but `literal_eval` cannot recognize it as the quotes are missing. For example, `[1929/01/17,1910/03/25]` should be `['1929/01/17','1910/03/25']` for it to work. You can either use substitution to add the missing quotes and then `literal_eval`. Another approach is simply to convert the string manually into a list of strings. Like this:

```
df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(','))
df['Country'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(','))
df['Assigned_ID'].apply(literal_eval)

print(df['DOB'][0][1])
```

Output:

```
1910/03/25
```

What we are doing is removing the brackets from the string and splitting the remaining string at the comma. The result is a string array of your values. For the column `Assigned_ID` you can use `literal_eval` as the array of numbers needs no quotes to be evaluated.

Comment: that's it. Works perfect except I needed to explicitly convert it to "str" first df_data['DOB'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(',')). Thanks(Y)

Comment: Glad I could help! Also, you are right it only works on strings.